# How to attach ImageView above BottomSheet?

Tags: android

I found this article

https://medium.com/android-bits/android-anchoring-views-to-bottom-sheet-9c9069caf7d4

Here explain the case what I need except one thing that I need to change. I changed `FloatingActionButton` to `ImageView` because I need to attach `ImageView` above `BottomSheet`.

So, my `xml`

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

.........

    <include layout="@layout/other_bottom_sheet_layout"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/ll_other_bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here screenshot

[image]

As you can see half of the image above the `BottomSheet` and half of image below...

I need a whole image to be exactly above

I tried to change a margin like this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/ll_other_bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />
```

And in initial state it looks ok

[image]

But when I expand `BottomSheet` I get such result

[image]

So, question is: how to attach ImageView above of BottomSheet and it should be above all the time, doesn't matter expand or collapsed bottomsheet...

Comment: Keep the image `<MY IMAGE>` as a part of bottom sheet layout itself.. Then it would be always above the bottom sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use margin for this. Use `layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"` attribute for the `ImageView`. Check [this](https://medium.com/@rusinikita/simple-view-dodging-with-coordinatorlayout-f13cc32e0de6) for more info.

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="170dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:src="@drawable/my_image"
   app:layout_anchor="@+id/ll_other_bottom_sheet"
   app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
   app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom" />
```

Comment: Worked for me when I added layout_insetEdge to the bottom sheet.

Comment: I love you, just had to figure out that you have to put app:layout_insetEdge="bottom" on the bottom sheet also (here: ll_other_bottom_sheet)